# Jogo do General em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde galera, estou fazendo o jogo do General (de dados em java).
Estou em dúvida em como comparar os dados entre eles.

Sequência
Possíveis sequências: 1-2-3-4-5 / 2-3-4-5-6 / 3-4-5-6-1
Número de pontos: 20

Full-Hand
O número x em 3 dados e o número y nos dois restantes (para x diferente de y)
Número de pontos: ( 3 * x + 2 * y ) + 30

Quadra
O número x em quatro dados diferentes
Número de pontos: ( 4 * x ) + 40

General
O número x nos cinco dados
Número de pontos: ( 5 * x ) + 50

Combinações Simples
Para cada número de 1 a 6 o jogador pode marcar pontos como no exemplo:
Ex: Se o jogador obtiver a seguinte sequência de números:   2   3   2   2   5

Até agora consegui fazer o teste para ver se é General:

```
 public int VerificarDados()
{
    int aux=1;
    int q=0,u;
    for(q=0;q<5;q++)
    {
        if(dados[q]==dados[q+1])
        {
            aux++;
        }
    }
    numRept=dados[1];
    if(aux==5)
    {
        return 5; //general
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dar alguma dica como fazer as outras comparações?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarde em um array de 6 elementos o número de ocorrências de cada dado (exemplo: se saíram três números 1, guarde na primeira casa do array o valor 3; se saíram quatro números 6, guarde na última casa do array o valor 4).

Aí você percorre o array em busca de cada condição que você quer (procura pela ocorrência de 5 números, se achar é um General; procura pela ocorrência de 3 números e pela ocorrência de 2 números, se achar as duas é Full-hand, senão é combinação simples; e assim por diante.

Comment: Dica muito boa! Valeu @Piovezan

Comment: Problema é que esta dando limite excedido no vetor, coloquei o código lá no chat se puderes me ajudar. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Lembre-se que um array que tenha por exemplo 5 elementos vai ter índices de 0 a 4. No código que você postou por exemplo não deve fazer o for até q < 5 e sim até q < 4 pois o dados[q+1] irá exceder o tamanho do array.